# Use Moq to do unit testing for datatable export service

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, moq

I have a service to export as csv file which inside videmodel in WPF application:

```
 public void ExportToExcel()
    {

        DataTable tblFiltered = _currentTable.AsEnumerable()
                          .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Type") == ExportGridGroup)
                          .CopyToDataTable();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        IEnumerable<string> columnNames = tblFiltered.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                          Select(column => column.ColumnName);
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

        foreach (DataRow row in tblFiltered.Rows)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => "\"" + field.ToString() + "\"");
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
        }

        String result = sb.ToString();
        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("export.csv");
            sw.WriteLine(result);
            sw.Close();
            Process.Start("export.csv");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

So based on this, i have created a test method for it but haven't finished;

```
 [TestMethod()]
    public void ExportToExcelTest()
    {
        //Step 1: Creating a mock table with columns
        DataTable testtable = new DataTable();
        DataRow mydatarow;
        mydatarow = testtable.NewRow();
        //Step 2: Adding the row 
        mydatarow["ColumnA"] = "12345";
        mydatarow["ColumnB"] = "test";

        testtable.Rows.Add(mydatarow);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        IEnumerable<string> columnNames = testtable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                          Select(column => column.ColumnName);
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

        foreach (DataRow row in testtable.Rows)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => "\"" + field.ToString() + "\"");
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
        }

        String result = sb.ToString();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("export.csv");
        sw.WriteLine(result);
        sw.Close();
        Process.Start("export.csv");          
        Assert.Fail();
    }
```

I am a bit confused because in the test method, I nearly write the exact same code in the project.....
Can I have some suggestions on how to write this unit test and any detailed references on WPF/C# Unit Testing by using Moq for me to start with?

Comment: There is a lot of tight coupling in the method under test and I do not see much opportunity to use Moq in that method effectively. Consider refactoring the method under test to rely on service abstractions that would allow it to be more testable in isolation.

Comment: A unit test should execute a method and assert the result. So you should make a call to `ExportToExcel` instead of recreating the logic. However, what @Nikosi said. This code is not really testable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider extracting the code in your `try` block to another service

```
public interface ICsvWriter
{
    void WriteOutput(string text);
}
```

and pass that as a dependency to your export service's contructor

```
public Service(ICsvWriter csvWriter)
{
    this.csvWriter = csvWriter;
}
```

Then, you can write a test like this to verify that it is actually outputting what you expect.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var csvWriter= new Mock<ICsvWriter>();
    var service = new Service(csvWriter.Object);
    string exportedText = string.Empty;

    // set up your mock so that whatatever string you pass in
    // gets passed to your exportedText variable.
    csvWriter.Setup(s => s.WriteOutput(It.IsAny<string>())).Callback<string>(s => exportedText = s);

    var testtable = new DataTable();
    // .... add test data

    // set the table on the view model
    service.SetData(testtable);

    // call the export method.
    service.ExportToExcel();

    // check that the result matches your expectation
    Assert.AreEqual("the text you expect to be written", exportedText);
}
```

**Update**

You can improve your test further by using parameterized testing to test different scenarios with the same test method.

If you're using MSTest, there's an attribute called DataRow. For xUnit, it's called InlineData or for NUnit, it's called TestCase. They all work like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow("12345", "test", "expected output text")]
[DataRow("abcde", "123", "expected output text")]
[DataRow("fghij", "456", "expected output text")]
public void TestMethod1(string columnA, string columnB, string expectedOutput)
{
    // ....
}
```

**Update**

You can also improve the testability of your export method by passing in the `DataTable` as a parameter. Then you can test it without having a public property for setting the data.

```
public void ExportToExcel(DataTable currentTable)
{
    DataTable tblFiltered = currentTable.AsEnumerable()
                          .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Type") == ExportGridGroup)
                          .CopyToDataTable();

    // ... 
}
```

**Another Update**

Actually, using a callback is unnecessary. Sorry, I should have suggested to do it this way which is cleaner:

Set up like this:

```
csvWriter.Setup(s => s.WriteOutput(It.IsAny<string>()));
```

Then verify this like this:

```
csvWriter.Verify(s => s.WriteOutput("expected text"), Times.Once);
```